# Where was The Sigilite during the fight for Terra?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I'm wondering if anybody knows where The Sigilite was during the Fight for Terra.

There is so much coming from Black Library in the past year and I just can't keep up anymore.

Is there a book or an audio drama, set during the period where Terra is under siege, where The Sigilite or his whereabouts are discussed?

Answer (score 4):

IIRC he was sitting on the Golden Throne, maintaining humanity's proto-webway while the Emperor was fighting. He did this at the cost of his sanity and life; he was wrenched away from the Throne to make space for the dying Emperor, and his body turned to dust.

He gave the last spark of power left in him to revive the Emperor, who then gave the orders to convert the Golden Throne from the centre of a new, human Webway to the life support system/psychic lighthouse it is in the post-Heresy Imperium.

The [Lexicanum page](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Malcador_%28Character%29) about Malcador cites [Horus Heresy: Visions of Death](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Horus_Heresy%3a_Visions_of_Death#Visions_of_Death) and the novel [Nemesis](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Nemesis_%28Novel%29) as sources of this information.

Comment: Yes... But this was durring the end of the siege??
Before that he gathered the 12 that would be the start of the Inquisition and we allready know some of their names.
Then he got them to Titan and hid the moon from Space and time for a period of years. Towards the end of the Heresy he somehow got to Terra through enemy lines so he could sit on the throne in stead of the Emperor so that the Emperor could go fight Horus. That is what i know. What im asking is does anybody know what he did before he sat sown on the throne?? The info is VERY vague!

Comment: _he was wrenched away from the Throne to make space for the dying Emperor, and his body turned to dust_... that sucks!